# Scanner always requires two inputs (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to implement a method that let's a player chose a username. The method suggests one based on the username of the currently running OS. Now I want to give the user the option to change his/her nickname, if he/she is not content with the suggestion. The problem now is, that I always have to enter my statement twice, as I guess either one is not being taken in.

(e.g. I have to enter:

"y"

"y")

I've tried altering the statement in the while loops (e.g. "nameChange.hasNextLine()"). I've tried to add "nameChange.nextLine();" befor and after "line = nameChange.nextLine();" (as a similar post on SO suggested) but neither worked.

```
public class SetUsername implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Suggests a name based on the accessing OS's user Let's the user change the suggestion to his
     * or her own username.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
      String name = System.getProperty("user.name");
      Scanner nameChange = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Your username is: " + name + ". Would you like to change it? (y/n)");
      String line;
      while (true) {
        line = nameChange.nextLine();
        if (line.equals("y")) {
          System.out.println("Chose a new username:");
          while(true) {
            name = nameChange.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Your new username is "+ name);
            break;
          }
          break;
        } else if (line.equals("n")) {
          break;
        } else {
          System.out.println("Invalid input. Your username is: " + name + ". "
              + "Would you like to change it? (y/n)");
        }
      }
      send(Command.SET_USERNAME, name);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: Why is this in a `Runnable`? Are you running more than one such task in parallel? If so, one task may be reading the input that was supposed to go to the other.

Comment: While the inner while loop is unnecessary in this example, the code is ok. I suspect, you are running it in multiple threads. Please, make sure you only run it once.

Comment: What is the point of `while(true) { ... break; }`?!?

Comment: You probably have some other method running before ending with a call to `next()` or `nextInt()`, and thus not consuming the line ending.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE] with a main method, that reliably reproduces your issue. As of now it seems the problem is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Thank you guys, it was that I had another Scanner running(as JB Nizet suggested). I managed to tie the start of said Scanner to a successfull choice of a username. Thank you (and sorry for partial unclear question structure, I will try to be more precise next time).

Answer (score 1):

"You probably have some other method running before ending with a call to next() or nextInt(), and thus not consuming the line ending." – JB Nizet

That was the problem.